# Can't update a column in a GridView with a DropDownList in its EditItemTemplate

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I'm trying to do a simple To-Do list application in ASP.NET with C# and I have a problem when I want to update the GridView with a value from a DropDownList. I've read a lot of solved question about this problem on this site but none of them worked so far or I must have missed something. Based on those answers I tried 2 method:

1. Method: I added a GridView to display and a FormView to add the Tasks. I created a database with a table for Tasks with Id, Name, Priority, DueDate, Completed columns and one table for priority possibilities(Low-Medium-High)
   My code looks this was:

ASP.NET GridView part:

```
 <asp:GridView ID="grdTasks" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowDataBound="grdTasks_RowDataBound" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" ForeColor="Black" GridLines="Vertical" OnRowEditing="grdTasks_RowEditing" AutoGenerateDeleteButton="True" AutoGenerateEditButton="True" OnRowCancelingEdit="grdTasks_RowCancelingEdit" OnRowUpdating="grdTasks_RowUpdating">

        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Id">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtId" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Id") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblId" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Id") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Priority">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlPriority" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="True">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblPriority" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Priority") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="DueDate" HeaderText="DueDate" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Completed">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Checkbox ID="chkCompleted" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Completed") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtCompleted1" runat="server" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
```

C# part:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            BindTasks();
        }

    }

    private void BindTasks()
    {
        SqlDataSource sqlDtsTasks = new SqlDataSource();
        sqlDtsTasks.ID = "sqlDtsTasks";
        this.Page.Controls.Add(sqlDtsTasks);
        sqlDtsTasks.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        sqlDtsTasks.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM Tasks";
        grdTasks.DataSource = sqlDtsTasks;
        grdTasks.DataBind();
    }

    protected void grdTasks_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {

            if ((e.Row.RowState & DataControlRowState.Edit) > 0)
            {

                DropDownList ddlPriority =
                          (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("ddlPriority");

                SqlDataSource sqlDtsTasks = new SqlDataSource();
                SsqlDtsTasks.ID = "sqlDtsTasks";
                this.Page.Controls.Add(sqlDtsTasks);
                sqlDtsTasks.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
                sqlDtsTasks.SelectCommand = "SELECT [States] FROM [Reference]";

                ddlPriority.DataSource = sqlDtsTasks;


                ddlPriority.DataTextField = "States";
                ddlPriority.DataValueField = "States";
                ddlPriority.DataBind();

                DataRowView dr = e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView;
                ddlPriority.SelectedValue =
                             dr["Priority"].ToString();
            }
        }

    }



    protected void grdTasks_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {

        grdTasks.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
        BindTasks();
    }


    protected void grdTasks_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
    {
        grdTasks.EditIndex = -1;
        BindTasks();
    }

    protected void grdTasks_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        SqlDataSource sqlDtsTasks = new SqlDataSource();
        sqlDtsTasks.ID = "sqlDtsTasks";
        this.Page.Controls.Add(sqlDtsTasks);
        sqlDtsTasks.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

        string Priotext = (grdTasks.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("ddlPriority") as DropDownList).SelectedItem.Value;
        string Id = (grdTasks.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].FindControl("txtId") as TextBox).Text;


        sqlDtsTasks.UpdateCommand = "UPDATE Tasks SET [Priority] = @Priority WHERE [Id] = @Id";

     -->   SqlDataSource2.UpdateParameters["Id"].DefaultValue = Id;
     -->   SqlDataSource2.UpdateParameters["Priority"].DefaultValue = Priotext;


        grdTasks.DataSource = sqlDtsTasks;
        grdTasks.DataBind();

    }
```

This way I get the following error from the line marked with the arrow:

> System.NullReferenceException - Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

This should mean that I got a null value from the ddl and the textbox but I dont know why, when I try to display the values of the ddl and textbox with a label, it displays it correctly.

2. Method: I basically did the same, but instead of doing it from code, I added 2 SqlDataSource. The first is binded to the GridView to display the Tasks. The second is binded to the DropDownList to display the Priority possibilities(Low-Medium-High). Also, I used the DataBindings from the smart tag of the DropDownList to bind the SelectedValue to the Priority column. This way, I can choose a priority when editing the row and I can update the Priority column if the current value in the db is null. BUT, when I want to update again, e.g. from Low to High I get this error:

   > System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException 'ddlPriority' has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items.

As I've read about this many people pointed out that I should add a code like this and set the AppendDataBoundItems to true:

`"<asp:ListItem Value=""></asp:ListItem>"`

I even tried to add a line for each value like the one above, still the same error. What do I missing?

Comment: on where you get the null reference exception?

Comment: At the following lines:  -->   SqlDataSource2.UpdateParameters["Id"].DefaultValue = Id;
            -->   SqlDataSource2.UpdateParameters["Priority"].DefaultValue = Priotext;